# RecyclerView don't accept Constructor from Model

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I can't understand why it makes problem with it. It take data from server with retrofit and it can't use that data in recyclerview. It make problem with Constructor but I can not understand why it makes problem with it. That can get data from service successfully with this Model, but problem is to put adapter and recyclierview. How can solve it?

[image]

ProductPage.java

```
public class ProductPage {
    private int productID;
    private String productName;
    private String productDescription;
    private List<String> productImages;
    private List<ProductPrice> productPrices;

    public int getProductID() {
        return productID;
    }

    public void setProductID(int productID) {
        this.productID = productID;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public String getProductDescription() {
        return productDescription;
    }

    public void setProductDescription(String productDescription) {
        this.productDescription = productDescription;
    }

    public List<String> getProductImages() {
        return productImages;
    }

    public void setProductImages(List<String> productImages) {
        this.productImages = productImages;
    }

    public List<ProductPrice> getProductPrices() {
        return productPrices;
    }

    public void setProductPrices(List<ProductPrice> productPrices) {
        this.productPrices = productPrices;
    }
}
```

ProductDetailAdapter.java

```
public class ProductDetailAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductDetailAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private Context mContext;
    int rawLayout;
    private List<ProductPage> productPageList;
    private int cartAmount;


    public ProductDetailAdapter(Context mContext,int rawLayout, List<ProductPage> productPageList, CartListener cartListener) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.rawLayout = rawLayout;
        this.productPageList = productPageList;
        this.cartListener = cartListener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ProductDetailAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int i) {
        View mView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(rawLayout, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(mView);    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {

        Glide.with(mContext).load(productPageList.get(position).getProductPrices().get(position).getShopImage())
                .apply(RequestOptions.placeholderOf(R.drawable.ic_glide_img).error(R.drawable.ic_glide_warning)).
                into(viewHolder.imgProductDetail);
        viewHolder.textProductDetailCost.setText(Double.toString(productPageList
                .get(position).getProductPrices().get(position).getShopProductPrice())+" TL");
        viewHolder.textProductDetailMarket.setText(productPageList.get(position).getProductPrices().get(position).getShopName());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return productPageList.size();
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private ImageView imgProductDetail;
        private TextView textProductDetailCost, textProductDetailMarket;
        private Button btnProductDetail;
        private CardView cardViewProductDetail;
        ViewHolder(View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            imgProductDetail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_product_detail);
            textProductDetailCost = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_product_detail_cost);
            textProductDetailMarket = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewProductShopName);
            btnProductDetail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonProductDetail);
            cardViewProductDetail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardViewProductDetail);
        }
    }
    public interface CartListener {
        void onProductSelect(ProductPage productPage);

    }
}
```

ProductActivity.java

```
  public class ProductActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ProductDetailAdapter.CartListener {
    TextView textProductName, textDescription;
    RecyclerView recyclerViewProduct;
    protected RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    String productCost, productMarket, productImage, productTitle, prdouctMarketImage;
    int id;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_product);
        init();
        loadProductPage();
    }

    private void init() {
        textProductName = findViewById(R.id.text_product_title);
        imgProduct = findViewById(R.id.img_product);
        recyclerViewProduct = findViewById(R.id.product_recycylerwiew);
        textDescription = findViewById(R.id.text_product_description);
        textDescription.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod()); // Scroll yapabilmek için açmıştım
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        recyclerViewProduct.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);


    private void loadProductPage() {
        ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getRetrofitInstance().create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<ProductPage> call = apiInterface.getProductPage(id);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ProductPage>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ProductPage> call, Response<ProductPage> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    ProductPage product_page_list = response.body();
                    textProductName.setText(product_page_list.getProductName());
                    textDescription.setText(product_page_list.getProductDescription());

                    Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(product_page_list.getProductImages())
                            .apply(RequestOptions.placeholderOf(R.drawable.ic_glide_img).error(R.drawable.ic_glide_warning)).
                            into(imgProduct);

                    ProductDetailAdapter myAdapter = new ProductDetailAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.product_detail_item_view,product_page_list,ProductActivity.this);
                    recyclerViewProduct.setAdapter(myAdapter);
                }
                else
                    ApiErrorUtils.parseError(response);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ProductPage> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("response","apiError");
            }
        });


    }



    @Override
    public void onProductSelect(ProductPage productPage) {
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just passing ProductPage object to adapter.

```
ProductPage product_page_list = response.body();
```

but your adapter required

```
List<ProductPage> productPageList
```

So you need to add product object to product list like this

```
 ProductPage productPage = response.body();
 List<ProductPage> productList=new ArrayList<>();
 productList.add(productPage);
```

Comment: thanks your code seem solved this problem. But for now it don't show other two elements in recyvlerview. Only show first one. Any ideas for it?

Comment: declare productlist globally because your are getting single object per request from api

Comment: I tried gloabally. I think there is another problem. Look my Model ProductPage.java. I need put this recyclierview array list of productPrices in ProductPage. There are 3 array inside of it. But it only take first one of it. I get so confused.

Comment: then you have to pass List<ProductPrice> in adapter

Answer (score 0):

```
ProductPage product_page_list = response.body();
```

product_page_list is not `List<ProductPage>()`

in your adapter need `List<ProductPage> productPageList`

Comment: So, How I should change it?